# Graphql date field type must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, postgraphql

I have a graphql server running with node/expres and ES6, I am trying to migrate to typescript, when I want to do graphql schema I have experiencing some problems with date types. I know that graphql does not contain a native date type, but in my ES6 implementation, I have used [graphql-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-date) to suply this limitation.

```
import {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID,
} from 'graphql';

import GraphQLDate from 'graphql-date';

const events = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'events',
    description: 'This represent an Event',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            id: {
                type: GraphQLID,
                resolve(event) {
                    return event.id;
                }
            },
            start: {
                type: GraphQLDate,
                resolve(event) {
                    return event.start;
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

the problem is that in my project with typescript when run server I get this message:

```
Error: events.start field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.
```

Comment: I solve the problem by myself, GraphqlDate not return any by default ant that's cause the problem, If I import as import * as ... date type works well

Comment: What was the solution exactly? Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that in TypeScript `import Foo from 'foo'` expects the module 'foo' to export a `module.exports.default` property. The `graphql-date` module instead does the classic Node.js pattern of overwriting `module.exports`.

To support this in TypeScript, you can mix the old and new syntax via:

```
import GraphQLDate = require('graphql-date');
```